# Making a custom Facebook sharer button with JS

Tags: javascript, html

I tried third part companies, but their resources slow my site down far too much so I've tried to make a facebook sharer button myself. It seems pretty basic Javascript; issue is, I'm very new to JS and I'm struggling a tad.

I need to generate whatever URL the page is on, and put it onto the end of the sharer url.

Currently I have:

```js
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = 
"https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=" + window.location.hostname;
```

```html
<a href="<p id='demo'></p>">Share</a>
```

Which should (I think) work, I think I'm along the right lines but I'm not too sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track. There is just one small change.

```
document.getElementById('demo').href = 
"https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=" + window.location.hostname;

<a id="demo" >Share</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. With this solution, I'm getting "TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById('demo').href = 
"https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=" + window.location.hostname')" as an error in the console.

Comment: document.getElementById() returns null if the element couldn't be found. Property assignment can only occur on objects. null is not an object. Are you sure the HTML is present when the JS was executed?

Comment: Works! I was putting the script in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best way to do but it should work for you

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.location.href= "https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=" + window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname">share</a>
```